# Javascript DOM manipulation with odd even class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have HTML like this

```
<div class="oddeven">
    <p id="p1" class="odd">Lorem ipsum</p>
    <p id="p2" class="even">dolor sit amet</p>
    <p id="p3" class="odd">consectetur adipiscing</p>
    <p id="p4" class="even">sed do</p>
    <p id="p5" class="odd">eiusmod tempor</p>
    <p id="p6" class="even">incididunt ut</p>
</div>
<button class="btnClick">Click</button>
```

I want to show only two paragraph like this

```
<div class="oddeven">
    <p id="p1" class="odd active">Lorem ipsum</p> // every 'odd' class will show here
    <p id="p2" class="even active">dolor sit amet</p> // every 'even' class will show here
</div>
<button class="btnClick">Click</button>
```

The rule is "Starting from '#p1', only one paragraph will change on click button, from odd to even, Odd class will change to another odd class, and even class will change to another even class".

Example first change will look like this (first button click)

```
<div class="oddeven">
    <p id="p3" class="odd active">consectetur adipiscing</p> // #p1 change to #p3
    <p id="p2" class="even active">dolor sit amet</p>
</div>
```

Example second change (second button click)

```
<div class="oddeven">
    <p id="p3" class="odd active">consectetur adipiscing</p>
    <p id="p4" class="even active">sed do</p> // #p2 change to #p4
</div>
```

Next button click will change odd, then even, odd, even, and so on..
Anyone please help me, I would highly appreciate..

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  var first_odd = $('.oddeven').children('.odd')[0];
  var first_even = $('.oddeven').children('.even')[0];

  $(first_odd).addClass('active');
  $(first_even).addClass('active');

  var odd_sibs = $(first_odd).siblings('.odd');
  var even_sibs = $(first_even).siblings('.even');

  $('.btnClick').on('click', function(){
    // I don't know what to do
  })
})
```

```css
.odd {
 color: red;
}
.even {
  color: blue;
}
.oddeven p {
  display: none;
}
.active {
  display: block!important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="oddeven">
 <p id="p1" class="odd">Lorem ipsum</p>
 <p id="p2" class="even">dolor sit amet</p>
 <p id="p3" class="odd">consectetur adipiscing</p>
 <p id="p4" class="even">sed do</p>
 <p id="p5" class="odd">eiusmod tempor</p>
 <p id="p6" class="even">incididunt ut</p>
</div>
<button class="btnClick">Click</button>
```

Comment: On first change, shouldn't it be `#p2 #p3`? Or you want to move the elements?

Comment: @Tushar first change (first button click) it should be #p2 #p3 because #p1 has been replaced to #p2

Comment: Then what's the point of the `odd/even` thing? Just show the next one and hide the first one!

Comment: @fandiahm - What you said in your comment that replied to Tushar "it should be #p2 #p3" seems to contradict all of the explanation in the question. Please confirm: do you always want the current "odd" element to be displayed *before* the current "even" element, even if the current "odd" element has a higher numbered ID?

Comment: Odd/even is class, every click button, p inside div.oddeven will change p alternatly by odd and even

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir the position should be like this <div><p>odd</p> <p>even</p></div> it always display 2 paragraph by odd and even. if we click button it will replace odd with next odd, then we click button again it will change even, click again change odd, and so on.. the position doesn't change, only the element replaces

Comment: If you want to make it like that then the order of the elements in the DOM should be odd, odd, ..., odd, even, even, ..., even! Unless you want to do it the hard way: detach-reatach!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's one way to do it:

```js
var odd = $(".odd")            // save a reference to the list of odd
var even = $(".even")          // and the list of even elements

odd.eq(0).addClass("active")   // display the first odd
even.eq(0).addClass("active")  // and first even

odd.prependTo(".oddeven")      // move the odd ones in front of the even
                               // so that when visible they'll always be
                               // before the even

var current = 0                // index of item currently shown
var next = odd                 // type to show next

$("button.btnClick").on("click", function() {
  if (next === odd)                             // if next is odd 
    current = (current + 1) % odd.length        // go to next index

  next.filter(".active").removeClass("active")  // deactivate previous one
  next.eq(current).addClass("active")           // activate next
  
  next = next === odd ? even : odd              // set which type to do next
})
```

```css
.odd { color: red; }
.even { color: blue; }
.oddeven p { display: none; }
.active { display: block!important; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="oddeven">
    <p id="p1" class="odd">p1 - Lorem ipsum</p>
    <p id="p2" class="even">p2 - dolor sit amet</p>
    <p id="p3" class="odd">p3 - consectetur adipiscing</p>
    <p id="p4" class="even">p4 - sed do</p>
    <p id="p5" class="odd">p5 - eiusmod tempor</p>
    <p id="p6" class="even">p6 - incididunt ut</p>
</div>
<button class="btnClick">Click</button>
```

Comment: Excellent..! Thank you soooo much.. I've spent hours to finish this. But one more question what is the meaning of this line : current = (current + 1) % odd.length EDITED : ok you have explained on next edit. Thank you very much

Comment: @fandiahm In simple words, go to first item from the last.

Comment: `current` is the index of which item we're up to. `current + 1` is the next item, but that will eventually run past the end of the list, so `% odd.length` uses the `%` "remainder" operator which divides `(current + 1)` by the length of the list and returns the remainder. This has the effect of "wrapping around" from the end of the list back to the start.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.filter()`, `:not()`, `:visible`, `:eq()`, `RegExp` `[135]` to check if a variable incremented from `0` is odd or even number; if `true` call `.hide()` on `p` elements having `.odd` `.className` which is `:visible`; select next `.even` element using variable, else do not `.hide()` `.even` `:visible` element, perform same operation

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var i = 0;
  $(".btnClick").on("click", function oddEven() {
    if (i === 0) {
      $(".oddeven p")
        .filter(".even:eq(" + i + "), .odd:eq(" + i + ")")
        .show()
        .toggleClass("active")
        .filter(".odd").css("top", "60px")
        .addBack()
        .filter(".even").css("top", "100px")
        ++i;
    } else {
      if (/[135]/.test(i)) {
        $(".oddeven p:not(.odd:visible)").hide()
          .removeClass("active")
          .filter(".even:eq(" + i + ")")
          .css("top", "100px")
          .show()
          .addClass("active")
      } else {
        $(".oddeven p:not(.even:visible)").hide()
          .removeClass("active")
          .filter(".odd:eq(" + i + ")")
          .css("top", "60px")
          .show()
          .addClass("active")
      }
      ++i
    }

    if (i === $(".oddeven p").length -1) {
      i = 0;
      $(".oddeven p")
      .css("top", "0px")
      .hide()
      .removeClass("active");
      oddEven()
    }
  })
})
```

```css
.odd {
  color: red;
}

.even {
  color: blue;
}

.oddeven p {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top:0px;
}

.active {
  display: block!important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="oddeven">
  <p id="p1" class="odd">Lorem ipsum</p>
  <p id="p2" class="even">dolor sit amet</p>
  <p id="p3" class="odd">consectetur adipiscing</p>
  <p id="p4" class="even">sed do</p>
  <p id="p5" class="odd">eiusmod tempor</p>
  <p id="p6" class="even">incididunt ut</p>
</div>
<button class="btnClick">Click</button>
```

Comment: Not even close!

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir _"Not even close!"_ Not sure what you mean?

Comment: This doesn't meet with OP's criteria cited in the question!

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir Yes it does as to selection of elements. Do you mean toggling `.className` and rendering of visible position of elements within parent element?

Comment: I know this conversation will probably end with us talking about god (like last time), But OP said: _the position should be like this <div><p>odd</p> <p>even</p></div> it always display 2 paragraph by odd and even. if we click button it will replace odd with next odd, then we click button again it will change even, click again change odd, and so on.. the position doesn't change, only the element replaces_! I hope it's clear!

Comment: Thanks for the answer @ibrahimmahrir Sorry if you mis-understanding what I explain, I'm not native english.

Comment: There should be always an `.odd` element and an `.even` element shown in that order. Clicking the button will replace either the `.odd` element with its next `.odd` element or `.even` element with its next `.even` element in turn (mean when clicking the button only one get changed, the other will change on the next click and so on)!

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir See updated post. Adjusted position using `css`, included adding and removing `"active"` `.className`

Comment: Yes thank you, but the first odd doesn't change.. The result should be like @nnnnnn answer

Comment: @fandiahm _"but the first odd doesn't change"_ Description of requirement at OP is _"Example first change will look like this (first button click)"_, _"Example second change (second button click)"_; `.odd` should not change until third `click` event, yes?

Answer (score 0):

Using `gt` and `lt` will lead to more maintainable code (as you can easily increase the number of elements.

```js
$(".oddeven").data("location", 0);
update();
  
function update() {
  loc = $(".oddeven").data("location") + 2;
  $(".oddeven").data("location", loc);
  $(".oddeven p").hide();
  $(".oddeven p:lt(" + loc + "):gt(-3)").show();
}
$('.btnClick').on('click', update);
```

```css
.oddeven p:nth-child(odd) {
 color: red;
}
.oddeven p:nth-child(even) {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="oddeven">
 <p id="p1">Lorem ipsum</p>
 <p id="p2">dolor sit amet</p>
 <p id="p3">consectetur adipiscing</p>
 <p id="p4">sed do</p>
 <p id="p5">eiusmod tempor</p>
 <p id="p6">incididunt ut</p>
</div>
<button class="btnClick">Click</button>
```